# two radial gradient colours, combined when joined

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a two radial gradient in canvas HTML5 and when I combine the two shapes, their colors combine, however, I want the colors to be separate, like in the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kk2tY/

I need as a minimum the transparency of color similar to this :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var rgba = new Array();
rgba[0] = new Array();
rgba[0][0] = [0, 255, 163, 0, 0.09];
rgba[0][1] = [0.3, 255, 168, 0, 0.07];
rgba[0][2] = [0.6, 255, 156, 0, 0.04];
rgba[0][3] = [1, 255, 169, 0, 0];

var x = 100,
    y = 75,
    // Radii of the white glow.
    innerRadius = 5,
    outerRadius = 70,
    // Radius of the entire circle.
    radius = 60;

ctx.beginPath();

var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, innerRadius, x, y, outerRadius);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,163,0,0.35)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.3, "rgba(255,168,0,0.24)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.6, "rgba(255,156,0,0.17)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255,169,0,0)");

ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();

var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(x + 45, y, innerRadius, x + 45, y, outerRadius);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,163,0,0.35)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.3, "rgba(255,168,0,0.24)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.6, "rgba(255,156,0,0.17)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255,169,0,0)");

ctx.arc(x + 45, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fill();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Atnt/

I have also tried with `context.globalAlpha` but the result was the same.

Comment: Could you try to explain more ? Do you want that the shared surface amongst two circles be filled with a single color like here : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/3Atnt/1/  ??

Comment: thanks, no, I want the same color when combine, don't different... sorry, but my english...

Comment: you should use a simple draw tool to build a small sketch of what you seek, 'a picture is worth a thousand words'...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kk2tY/ this exameple with alpha...

Answer (score 0):

When you use transparency, then all the different colors of a pixel will be added to get the final result.

If that's not the desired result, you're on your own.

What you need to do is draw a diagram (on paper) where you select various points and determine manually which color they should have.

Then look at all the points and try to come up with an algorithm that produces those results.

Finally, you need to convert that algorithm into JavaScript probably using a "pixel-by-pixel" rendering approach.

Another approach is to render the two shapes into two images and then use image processing to combine them according to certain rules. Google for `html5 canvas image processing`.

Comment: Google for "html5 canvas image processing".